# In Angular6 application app component is not loading(taking)

Tags: angular6

In angular6 application, it is running perfectly and console also not showing any errors but app component is not taking because of my project code or versions issue I didn't get. Even for debugging also not triggering.

When it comes to angular 6 angular.json is there replace of angular-cli

[image]

Below is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@turf/inside": "^5.0.0",
    "@turf/turf": "^5.1.6",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.3",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
    "@types/kurento-utils": "^6.7.0",
    "@types/loader-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.1.2",
    "@types/openlayers": "^4.6.9",
    "@types/simplebar": "^2.4.1",
    "@types/tapable": "^1.0.2",
    "acorn-dynamic-import": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
    "angular-io-slimscroll": "^2.3.3",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "bpmn-js": "^0.30.0",
    "bpmn-js-properties-panel": "^0.22.1",
    "buffer": "^5.1.0",
    "compodoc": "0.0.41",
    "constants": "0.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "d3": "^4.12.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "domain": "0.0.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "events": "^3.0.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.4",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "geojson2shape": "^0.2.4",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "inherits": "^2.0.3",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "json-logic-js": "^1.2.2",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
    "kurento-utils": "^6.6.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "loader-utils": "^1.0.2",
    "microsoft-applicationinsights-angular5": "^0.1.6",
    "mxgraph-js": "^1.0.1",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "^4.2.0",
    "ng2draggable": "^1.3.2",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ng4-shared-module": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^5.3.8",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-scroll-event": "^1.0.8",
    "node": "10.0.0",
    "node-require": "0.0.10",
    "npm-sass": "^2.2.1",
    "papaparse": "^4.5.0",
    "preboot": "^6.0.0-beta.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.3.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "shp-write": "^0.3.2",
    "shpjs": "^3.4.2",
    "simplebar": "^2.6.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "svg-loader": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "turf": "^3.0.14",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "videogular2": "^6.0.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
```

Below are my versions

```
 Angular-cli version:6.0.8
    node -v:8.9.4
```

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: Provide your code for app folder. And mani.ts file

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale There is no errors as I mentioned.

Comment: produce a plucker

Comment: cause your question is not clear or not quickly understandable!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale actually the problem is I have previously worked for angular 5.2.0 version with angular cli.json.here is working but when I am using ng build command I am getting an error regarding but I am facing an issue regarding  TypeScript compilation, Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

Comment: Then it would be better if you post that error also which caused a problem while using ng build cmd